# Merge specific column in multiple dataframe with different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns

**df1**

```
    Color   date
0   A       2011
1   B       201411
2   C       20151231
3   A       2019
```

**df2**

```
    Color   date
0   A       2013
1   B       20151111
2   C       201101
```

**df3**

```
    Color   date
0   A       2011
1   B       201411
2   C       20151231
3   A       2019
4   Y       20070212
```

Assuming there are three dataframes:
I want to create a new dataframe by extracting only the 'date' column.

**output what I want**

**New df**

```
    df1-date  df2-date  df3-date     
0   2011      2013      2011
1   201411    20151111  201411
2   20151231  201101    20151231
3   2019      NaN       2019
4   NaN       NaN       20070212
```

I want to set the empty part to NaN because the length is different.

I try merge,concat but getting error..

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more approach

```
df1.join(df2['date'],rsuffix='df2',how='outer').join(df3['date'],rsuffix='df3',how='outer')
```

**Output**

```
  Color     date        datedf2     datedf3
0   A       2011.0      2013.0      2011
1   B       201411.0    20151111.0  201411
2   C       20151231.0  201101.0    20151231
3   A       2019.0      NaN         2019
4   NaN     NaN         NaN         20070212
```

Comment: More intuitive, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This include two problem, 1 multiple dataframes `merge`, 2 duplicated key merge

```
def multikey(x): 
    return x.assign(key=x.groupby('Color').cumcount())

#we use groupby and cumcount create the addtional key

from functools import reduce

#then use reduce

df = reduce(lambda left,right: 
            pd.merge(left,right,on=['Color','key'],how='outer'), 
            list(map(multikey, [df1,df2,df3])))
df
  Color      date_x  key      date_y      date
0     A      2011.0    0      2013.0      2011
1     B    201411.0    0  20151111.0    201411
2     C  20151231.0    0    201101.0  20151231
3     A      2019.0    1         NaN      2019
4     Y         NaN    0         NaN  20070212
```

Notice name here we can always modify by `rename`

Method 2 from `cancat` not consider the key one merge with index

```
s=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],keys=['df1','df2','df3'], axis=1)
s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)
s=s.filter(like='_date')
s
     df1_date    df2_date  df3_date
0      2011.0      2013.0      2011
1    201411.0  20151111.0    201411
2  20151231.0    201101.0  20151231
3      2019.0         NaN      2019
4         NaN         NaN  20070212
```

Comment: In method 2 got an error `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (405, 12), indices imply (199, 12)`.. In my real data. But thank you for your comment!